# Creating multiple dataframe using loop or function

Tags: python, pandas, database, dataframe, dictionary

I'm trying to extract the hash rate for 3 cryptocurrencies and I have attached the code for the same below. Now, I want to pass three urls and in return I need three different different dictionaries which should have the values. I'm stuck and I don't understand how should I go about it. I have tried using loops but it is not working out for me.

```
url = {'Bitcoin' : 'https://bitinfocharts.com/comparison/bitcoin-hashrate.html#3y', 
       'Ethereum': 'https://bitinfocharts.com/comparison/ethereum-hashrate.html#3y',
       'Litecoin': 'https://bitinfocharts.com/comparison/litecoin-hashrate.html'}

for ele in url:
    
    #### requesting the page and extracting the script which has date and values
    session = requests.Session()
    page = session.get(ele[i])
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
    values = str(soup.find_all('script')[4])
    values = values.split('d = new Dygraph(document.getElementById("container"),')[1]

    #create an empty dict to append date and hashrates
    dict([("crypto_1 %s" % i,[]) for i in range(len(url))])

    #run a loop over all the dates and adding to dictionary
    for i in range(values.count('new Date')):
        date = values.split('new Date("')[i+1].split('"')[0]
        value = values.split('"),')[i+1].split(']')[0]
        dict([("crypto_1 %s" % i)[date] = value
```

Comment: Could you please be specific about what you mean by loops not working? Do you get an error message? Do they simply not behave as expected?

Comment: Please include all `import` lines for [mcve]. Where are your three URLs? Show us the long, non-loop way.

Comment: I have updated. What I'm trying to do is to get the values of date and hashrate of three crypto in a dictionary. I have created 3 dictionaries and each dictionary should have the values of 3 crypto. I'm a bit stuck on how to do it. I hope it is clear now.

Comment: Once again, please include all `import` lines and if loop is troubling you, please show the long way of doing what you need without looping. Post code for *one* URL for example. You must have done it the long way to even have written this piece. By the way, as @AJH asks, what is specifically wrong with this code? Errors? Undesired results? Also, where are you using pandas or data frames, tagged and in title?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use next example how to get data from all 3 URLs and create a dataframe/dictionary from it:

```py
import re
import requests
import pandas as pd


url = {
    "Bitcoin": "https://bitinfocharts.com/comparison/bitcoin-hashrate.html#3y",
    "Ethereum": "https://bitinfocharts.com/comparison/ethereum-hashrate.html#3y",
    "Litecoin": "https://bitinfocharts.com/comparison/litecoin-hashrate.html",
}


data = []
for name, u in url.items():
    html_doc = requests.get(u).text
    for date, hash_rate in re.findall(
        r'\[new Date\("(.*?)"\),(.*?)\]', html_doc
    ):
        data.append(
            {
                "Name": name,
                "Date": date,
                "Hash Rate": float("nan")
                if hash_rate == "null"
                else float(hash_rate),
            }
        )

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df["Date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Date"])
# here save df to CSV

# this will create a dictionary, where the keys are crypto names and values
# are dicts with keys Date/HashRate:
out = {}
for name, g in df.groupby("Name"):
    out[name] = g[["Date", "Hash Rate"]].to_dict(orient="list")

print(out)
```

Prints:

```
{
    "Bitcoin": {
        "Date": [
            Timestamp("2009-01-03 00:00:00"),
            Timestamp("2009-01-04 00:00:00"),
            Timestamp("2009-01-05 00:00:00"),

...
```